# Spring Boot Rest call according to parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have a question about the following. We want to create some Rest calls. One of the parameters of the rest calls is the return format. So the parameter return_format can have the values json or xml. Is there a smart way to use the parameter and use the service that will produce the right output format?

If the call parameter return_format == json then

```
@Produces({"application/json"})
```

if the call parameter return_format == xml then

```
@Produces({"application/xml"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a parameter like return_format. This can be controlled with the Accept header.

In the controller you can add both formats:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces = { "application/json", "application/xml" })
public <yourResponse> get(@RequestHeader("Accept") String accept) {
    // Check if Accept is XML or JSON
}
```

Comment: Dear @Simon Martinelli thank you very much for your answer. The case and problem here is, that we only have the rest call with the parameters nothing else (No UI). So only with the given url : http://localhost:8080/api/getData?return_format=JSON or http://localhost:8080/api/getData?return_format=XML, I can recognize what format I should return.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how to the the Accept header information